# Can we get an early Data Explorer update for Ask Different, for playing with contest data?

Tags: support, data-explorer

The [Ask Different data](http://data.stackexchange.com/apple/queries) on Data Explorer was last updated before the contest opened. Is there a chance it could be updated sooner than next month, so we can worry ourselves sick trying to interpret and test the fine points of the rules? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use the API? The documentation for the API includes a reasonably user friendly console for you to retrieve data, although the response is in JSON.

Comment: Yes, I realized this later on. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It would be interesting as a single point for data, but it wouldn't be that helpful unless it was updated daily for the full next week.

Besides, those that are really interested in playing the game can just go to each competitor's user page and do the work by hand.

I'm interested in seeing the slope of each's reputation, since that's what will matter by the end of the contest, as both level 2 and 3 will have more winners than prizes.

On the other hand, the stack exchange API would be able to provide that information for the interested programmer...

Comment: Good luck divining my slope :-) also, bounties

Comment: @bmike http://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike?tab=reputation Tada!  Your slope is steeper than mine, so as long as you get your act together and start sharing links, you'll be more likely to get an ipad than I will.

Comment: Pretty much this. Using the API would be your best bet for up-to-date information.